# CKEditor add form/input into toolbar

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to create plugin, where user can set custom font size. Increase and decrese button I already have, but I have problem with input.

It should looks like this: [image]
(this is screenshot from antoher text editor, not ckeditor!)

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm trying to do something similar at the minute.

Comment: Yes, we did it, I think it was 1 week after this question. By the time, we edited it and removed [+] [-] buttons, so we have just select and inpit elements. Also, we add [Line height] option and fully rewritten 4 other plugins. Today, our company TinyMCE does not look like TinyMCE :) My boss will not allow me to publish that much code, but you can visit our site/software and see, how it works and etc, it will be OK with both sides. Site: http://creedoo.com/ -> TinyMCE is in editor mode, so you will need to register and create a presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [the Font addon](http://ckeditor.com/addon/font), for CKEditor. It should give you a good start, the only thing missing would be the +/- button, which as you said you have.

After downloading and placing in the addon folder you can enable it as any other CKEditor addon - by adding it to the `extraPlugins` during initialisation:

```
extraPlugins: 'font',
```

Comment: I need that textbox, where you can type, for example 25 and after enter press it change font size. I have plugin `font`, also modyfied by me.

Comment: hi @dropout, did you ever get this working? I'm trying to do something similar at the minute.

Comment: @roryok what exactly do you mean by "get it working"? it's a plugin for CKEditor, just follow the installation instructions found here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_plugins

Comment: sorry, I meant to ask OP if he got his modifcations working. username mix up. my bad